# Rails remove comment with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have problem with removing comments with AJAX. When I'm deleting comment nothing happens on page until refresh, but data is deleted in database. I was searching for this topic for more than 2 hours and still wasnt able to find anwser.

Views:

```
#annoucements/show.html.haml
=render @comments

#comments/_comment.html.haml
%ul
 %p
  %b User:
   = comment.user.username
   = time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)
 %p
  %b Content:
    = comment.content
  - if comment.user.id == current_user[:id]
    = link_to 'Delete comment', annoucement_comment_path(@annoucement, comment), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, remote: true
```

Controller:

```
#comment_controller.rb
def destroy
  @annoucement = Annoucement.find(params[:annoucement_id])
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @annoucement }
    format.js
  end
end
```

JS:

```
#destroy.js.erb

$('#comment_<%= @comment.id %>').remove();
```

Console:

```
Started DELETE "/annoucements/9/comments/142" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-26 01:11:53 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as JS
Parameters: {"annoucement_id"=>"9", "id"=>"142"}
Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 142], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Annoucement Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "annoucements".* FROM "annoucements" WHERE "annoucements"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 142], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 142]]
(82.4ms)  commit transaction
Rendering comments/destroy.js.erb
Rendered comments/destroy.js.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 95ms (Views: 5.7ms | ActiveRecord: 82.9ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: show your comments view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js is trying to erase the element with id @comment_XXX (XXX is the id of the erased comment). But you have not set this id. Add it to the div that contains the comment

```
%ul{:id => "comment_#{comment.id}"}
  %p
    %b User:
      = comment.user.username
      = time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)
    etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, not exacly code that you gave because in HAML it should be `%ul{:id => "comment_#{comment.id}"}`, but still thank you very much that's was helpful.